# How to add XML output formatter to ASP.Net Boilerplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

ASP.NET Core 2.2, ASP.Net Boilerplate version 4.1, Modul Zero Core version 4.4.0 is used.
The API accepts JSON objects as input and returns JSON objects. I was faced with the task of ensuring the possibility of using XML in conjunction with JSON.
I tried it like this:

```
// file RootNs.Web.Mvc Startup.cs
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    // ...
    services.AddMvc(options => {

        options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());

        options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
        options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<HttpNoContentOutputFormatter>();
        options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;

        options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
        // so also tried
        // options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());

        options.FormatterMappings
        .SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("xml", MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/xml"));
    })
}
```

After that, I decorated the method in the API with the FormatFilter attribute. But it did not help.
How to add support for XML output formater? In which project (*.Web.Mvc or *.Web.Host) should the file Startup.cs be edited?

Comment: Add it in the host project. It's the WebAPI exposer